# Change headers of smfbook.cls

Tags: header-footer, theorems, templates, amsthm

I'm using a template which is essentially the smfbook template (provided [here](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/Formats/)). I love it, but I would like to change some details:

The first is the headers. By default, in even pages we get ''CHAPTER X. TITLE OF THE CHAPER''. I would like to remove the first part ''Chapter X''. Also, in odd pages, it writes X.2 THE NAME OF SECTION 2. I would like to get ''S (the section symbol `\S`)2. THE NAME OF SECTION 2''. The part for the headers is here:

```
    % Headers
\def\ps@empty{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \let\@oddhead\@empty \let\@evenhead\@empty
  \let\@oddfoot\@empty \let\@evenfoot\@empty
  \global\topskip\normaltopskip}
\def\ps@plain{\ps@empty
  \def\@oddfoot{\normalfont\scriptsize \hfil\thepage\hfil}%
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
\def\ps@headings{\ps@empty
  \def\@oddfoot{}%
  \def\@evenfoot{}%
  \def\@evenhead{\normalfont\scriptsize
     \rlap{\bfseries\thepage}\hfil \leftmark{}{}\hfil}%
  \def\@oddhead{\normalfont\scriptsize
     \hfil \rightmark{}{}\hfil \llap{\bfseries\thepage}}%
  \let\@mkboth\markboth
  \def\partmark    {\@secmark\markboth\partrunhead\partname}%
  \def\chaptermark {\@secmark\markboth\chapterrunhead\chaptername}%
  \def\sectionmark {\@secmark\markright\sectionrunhead\sectionname}%
  \def\indexmark   {\@secmark\markboth\indexrunhead\indexname}%
}


\let\ps@copyright\ps@empty
\def\ps@myheadings{\ps@headings \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo}
\def\leftmark{\expandafter\@firstoftwo\topmark{}{}}
\def\rightmark{\expandafter\@secondoftwo\botmark{}{}}
\long\def\@nilgobble#1\@nil{}
\def\@secmark#1#2#3#4{%
  \begingroup \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
  \edef\@tempa{\endgroup \toks@{\@nx#2{#3}{\@secnumber}}}%
  \@tempa
  \toks@\@xp{\the\toks@{#4}}%
  \afterassignment\@nilgobble\@temptokena\@themark{}\@nil
  \edef\@tempa{\@nx\@mkboth%
    {\ifx\markright#1\the\@temptokena\else\the\toks@\fi}%
    {\the\toks@}}%
  \@tempa}
\let\@secnumber\@empty
\def\markboth#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \@temptokena{{#1}{#2}}\xdef\@themark{\the\@temptokena}%
    \mark{\the\@temptokena}%
  \endgroup
  \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi}
\let\partmark\@gobble
\let\tocmark\@gobble
\let\sectionmark\@gobble
\let\subsectionmark\@gobble
\let\subsubsectionmark\@gobble
\let\paragraphmark\@gobble
```

but I don't know how to change it.
Notice that since I have the code the idea is to avoid the use of some extra package, such as `fancyhdr`for example.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{sfmbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\author{Me}
\title{My book}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}
\section{A}

\begin{remark}
This is a remark.
\end{remark}

And this is a theorem
\begin{theorem}
Hello :)
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[1-5]
\section{B}
\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter{Two}
\section{A}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{B}
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{C}
\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter{Three}
\section{A}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{B}
\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter{Four}
\section{A}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{B}
\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter{Five}
\section{A}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{B}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This are two different questions. I will answer only the first one. Maybe you can ask a new question for the second issue.

You have to redefine `\chapterrunhead`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\chapterrunhead#1#2#3{%
  \@ifnotempty{#3}{\MakeUppercase{#3}}%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

and `\sectionmarkhead`

```
\makeatletter
\def\sectionmark{\@secmark\markright\sectionrunhead\S}
\makeatother
```

[image]

and maybe `\sectionrunhead`

```
\makeatletter
\def\sectionrunhead#1#2#3{%
  \@ifnotempty{#2}
    {\MakeUppercase{#1 \arabic{section}}\@ifnotempty{#3}{.\ }}%
  \@ifnotempty{#3}{\MakeUppercase{#3}}%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{smfbook}

\makeatletter
\def\chapterrunhead#1#2#3{%
  \@ifnotempty{#3}{\MakeUppercase{#3}}%
}
\def\sectionmark{\@secmark\markright\sectionrunhead\S}
\def\sectionrunhead#1#2#3{%
  \@ifnotempty{#2}
    {\MakeUppercase{#1 \arabic{section}}\@ifnotempty{#3}{.\ }}%
  \@ifnotempty{#3}{\MakeUppercase{#3}}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\author{Me}
\title{My book}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}
\section{A}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{B}
\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter{Two}
\section{A}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{B}
\lipsum[1-5]
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{C}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Okey. I'll modifiy the question and deleted the second one. I'm also going to try the code. If it works (I'm sure it will) I'll accept your answer. Thanks.